# How to kill all network access to linux iso

Tags: linux, networking, software-rec

I am trying to set up a Linux environment on a laptop that is completely unable to have any network communication from a software angle.
No WiFi, No Bluetooth, No Ethernet.(Inbound and outbound)

To start I am using bodhi linux (for its small size)
as I was having issues adding repositories using slax linux.

After making a fresh install there are a number of applications I need to install on the iso before configuring it to be completely offline.

The reason for this is from a security perspective to prevent any possible hacks.

I know it might seem like a silly question,
but I cant seem to find any answer anywhere as my searches keep throwing back
links and questions to people asking for help enabling network access.
whilst I want to completely kill it.

Comment: look at disabling those network devices in the laptop BIOS

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own ISO with a custom-built kernel without any network driver of any kind. You can also uninstall `linux-firmware` package. In higher level you can disable/remove NetworkManager, DHCP and such programs which configures network. In hardware level, you can pull off your NIC.